# Problem related to parent and child element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie in Javascript coding. I wanted to do a mobile menu where if I click outside of the menu - the menu will disappear. I have done it successfully.

Now the problem is when I am clicking on the **hamburger** icon, the menu is not expanding. But when I am clicking on its parent element, it's working fine.

What's wrong in my Javascript code?

[image]

My code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #146875;
  
}


.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffFF;   /*font color*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #00e5ff;  /*top nav menu back hover color*/
  
  
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px)  /* Mobile Screen Breakdown */
{
  .topnav a:not(:nth-child(-n+3)) {
      display: none;
}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" >
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#floorplan">about Us</a>
        <a href="#address">Address</a>
  
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

var disappear = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.parentNode !== disappear){
    disappear.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is

```
if (event.target.parentNode !== disappear ){
    disappear.className = "topnav";
}
```

when you are clicking on the icon( i tag) the parent node is the anchor tag. so its true. I have changed the code to below. And this should work for your example, also check the whole code snippet below

```
if (event.target.parentNode !== disappear && event.target.parentNode.parentNode !== disappear)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #146875;
  
}


.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffFF;   /*font color*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #00e5ff;  /*top nav menu back hover color*/
  
  
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px)  /* Mobile Screen Breakdown */
{
  .topnav a:not(:nth-child(-n+3)) {
      display: none;
}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav" >
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#floorplan">about Us</a>
        <a href="#address">Address</a>
  
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

var disappear = document.getElementById('myTopnav');
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.parentNode !== disappear && event.target.parentNode.parentNode !== disappear){
    disappear.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```